# spark shell (spark 2.4, scala 2.11.12 ) can not recognize imported class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use spark 2.4 and scala 2.11.12, in the spark shell, I hit very weird issue, that it can not recognize imported class. Is it a bug of scala 2.11.12, because it works in scala 2.12 and 2.11.8

```
scala> import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.ArrayList

scala> class A extends ArrayList {}
<console>:11: error: not found: type ArrayList
       class A extends ArrayList {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You using which JDK?

With JDK 11, it works :

```
Using Scala version 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.2)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.ArrayList

scala> class A extends ArrayList
defined class A
```